# Pass Field Value From CRM Form into Lookup RetrieveMultiple Message

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am altering the currency search for CRM 2011 by processing in a C# plugin the RetrieveMultiple message's query before it is executed.  When the currency lookup search is used on my form, I need to display currencies that are valid for use by a specific office.  I have the fetchxml that works correctly (i.e. the logic is correct), but my problem is I cannot find a way to

1. check if the RetrieveMultiple message is due to a lookup field on my form (so I know to do #2 below), and
2. get the office field id from the form that whose currency lookup search triggered the RetrieveMultiple message

Do RetrieveMultiple messages contain some context about what entity or control triggered them?  Is there some other way to know what form triggered the event?

Comment: Have you considered filtered lookup? Seems to be more easy to achieve and gives error earlier than when user saves/updates record.

Comment: I've used filtered lookups on a few other custom fields with ease, but I could not set my custom view as default on the currency field.  The reason seemed to be that currency was a system default field, hence it is locked down more than custom fields.  Have you experienced that?

Comment: Haven't tried this on currency field. Alternatively you can try to use JScript as described [here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/08/05/creating-custom-filtered-lookup-crm-2011/)

Comment: That is my setup precisely which works for a few other fields.  It doesn't work on the currency field though - presumably because it is a special kind of system field.  The view gets generated successfully, but I cannot force the lookup to use the new view.  This is good information for others to see.